# Testing a constructed function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to understand how to effectively test objects in JavaScript. I understand that `deepEqual` checks constructors as well as properties, but I'm wondering if the test below is a valid test or if it's redundant.

```js
function CustomThing(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

test('Object deepEqual', function(assert) {

    function localCustomThing(a, b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }

    function testCustomThing() {
      return new CustomThing('hello', 'world');
    }

    const foo = new CustomThing('hello', 'world');
    const bar = new localCustomThing('hello', 'world');
    const fizz = testCustomThing();

    assert.deepEqual(foo, bar) // fail
    assert.deepEqual(foo, fizz) // pass
})
```

Now, I understand why the second test passes, but I'm wondering *if* this is a valid test structure. I know this is a simple example, but is it redundant to call the same constructor through a wrapper with the same input parameters? How should a test on a constructor function be built?

Comment: why are you calling the constructor through a wrapper? If you can't give a reason, then maybe you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Jhecht That's what I'm wondering. How can I check that constructor actually returns what I expect? Is it best practice in this situation to check the props only?